# Trackpad Problems in both 16.04 LTS and 17.10

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, mouse, 17.10, touchpad

Recently tried installing both ubuntu 16.04 lts and 17.10 on an older laptop to try it out and maybe use it for work later down the line. It's a Toshiba u495-s4380. I've tried all I could find regarding fixes, and nothing works. Editing the GRUB file, downloading the synaptics drivers, updating ubuntu, etc.

on 16.04, when i download the synaptics drivers the keyboard stops functioning along with the trackpad and any USB devises.

on 17.10, keyboard and USB devices work (like an external mouse), but the trackpad wont work at all.

A the same 16.04 LTS issues occurs on zorin 12.